# Slack API - create a post using curl

Tags: curl, slack-api

we can post messages by using slack api.
how can I "create a post" through slack api on curl command interface?

ref: third item "create a post" http://gyazo.com/fc00f2ba2af66b4d6843e89a24c33be3

I've tried some request as follows.

```
curl -F file=@post_contents.txt -F channels=sample -F token=SOME_SLACK_TOKEN -F filetype=posts -F title=some_title https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

I want not to create a text file but to create a post.
best

Answer (score 5):

Rather than `posts` as your filetype, use `post`